# Difference between JavaBean, POJO and normal class?

Tags: java, javabeans, pojo

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between a JavaBean and a POJO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394265/what-is-the-difference-between-a-javabean-and-a-pojo)
>   [Difference between DTO, VO, POJO, JavaBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans)

Could you please explain the difference between JavaBean, POJO class and normal class in Java technology?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a JavaBean and a POJO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394265/what-is-the-difference-between-a-javabean-and-a-pojo) and [Difference between DTO, VO, POJO, JavaBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans)

Comment: please check the `related` list on the right hand column (you should also have seen this list popped up while you was entering the subject and question message).

Answer (score 0):

Not much.

A JavaBean has to follow certain naming conventions laid down in the JavaBean spec, but otherwise they are all the same.

Comment: Not actually. Check the answer of Pascal Thivent in 2nd duplicate topic link.

Comment: Err... which says exactly what I said! Discounting the stuff about DAOs and VOs (which the OP didn't ask about), he says that JavaBeans are just POJOs that follow specific conventions, and POJOs are just regular Java classes. Nutter.