# Can POJO and CDI beans be instantiated from the same class?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi, pojo

It might be extremely basic... In Java EE 6 enviroment:

Can POJO and CDI beans be instantiated from the same class?

What is the fundamental difference between a *CDI* bean and a *POJO*?

Probably this question would be useful to beginneers in Java EE Container Managed applications.

Comment: This question has been asked a million times, with a million great answers...

Comment: please link **exact** duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149932/difference-between-javabean-pojo-and-normal-class?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394265/what-is-the-difference-between-a-javabean-and-a-pojo
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612334/difference-between-dto-vo-pojo-javabeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Very basically, a POJO is normally instantiated with **new** operator, and a CDI bean is instantiated (managed) by the container. So the same class can instantiate both POJOs and CDI beans.