# How to add the fetched data in ArrayList<Object> in doInBackground [Android]

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My goal is to put the fetched `JSON` in my `ArrayList<Object>` to be able to display my `ListView` I'm searching for syntax how to do it but I'm confuse on how to do it correctly.

here's my code

```
public class MyListActivity extends ActivityWithTabBar implements
    OnGestureListener, OnTouchListener {

  private String searchText = null;
  private ArrayList<ListItems> itemsArray = null;
  private MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter;
  private ListView lv = null;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  searchText = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.SEARCH).trim();
  performSearch();

  }

  private void performSearch() {
    searchText = editTextSearch.getText().toString();
    loadDataViaWS();
  }

  private void loadDataViaWS(){
    itemsArray = new ArrayList<ListItems>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSearch);
    this.myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listview_row_2rows_subtitle, itemsArray);
    lv.setAdapter(this.myArrayAdapter);

    new GetValues().execute();
}
```

Here is my `AsyncTask`

```
class GetValues extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ListItems>> { 
 private final String URL_STRING = url;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL_STRING);
String jsonData = null;

@Override 
 protected ArrayList<ListItems> doInBackground(Void... params){
 try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            jsonData =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("JSON:", jsonData));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

itemsArray = new ArrayList<ListItems>();
        JSONObject object = null;
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray jArray  = object.getJSONArray("DATA");

            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String Id = jObj.getString("id");
                String Name = jObj.getString("name");
                String Description = jObj.getString("description");


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
}
```

As you can see in my `doInBackground` inside the `for` loop how will I put the `JSONObject` I fetched in my `itemsArray` where `itemsArray` is equal to  `ArrayList<ListItems>` ?

**Edit**

Here is my ListItems

```
public class ListItems implements Serializable {
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private String description;

 public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: What is `ListItems`? Is it some kind of data holder class that contain `Id`, `Name` and `Description`?

Comment: create pojo class like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11722289/3946555, then set the values to your pojo class using setter method, then add this class into your arraylist. and then return arraylist.

Comment: @Abbas I added my `ListItems` please check.

Comment: @Madhan i have a class like that. Where it is the `ListItems`

Comment: check my answer and do have a look at the link @Madhan provided.

Comment: show your json response?

Comment: @mori see my answer I've  edited your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've modified your code look into it

```
    class GetDealsByNameDescAdd extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ListItems>> { 
     private final String URL_STRING = url;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL_STRING);
    ArrayList<ListItems> itemsArray;
    String jsonData = null;

    @Override 
     protected ArrayList<ListItems> doInBackground(Void... params){
     try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                jsonData =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("JSON:", jsonData));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    itemsArray = new ArrayList<ListItems>();
            JSONObject object = null;
            try {
                object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                JSONArray jArray  = object.getJSONArray("DATA");

                for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    ListItems item=new ListItems();

                    //String Id = jObj.getString("id"); //replce this with following code
                    item.setId(jObj.getString("id"));

                    //String Name = jObj.getString("name");  //replce this with following code
                    item.setName(jObj.getString("name"));

                    //String Description = jObj.getString("description");   //replce this with following code
                    item.setDescription(jObj.getString("description"));

                    itemsArray.add(items);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //if there is an exception in parsing json then it returns null
                return null;
            }


            return itemsArray;
    }
    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ListItems> items){
        if(items!=null){
            //here you will receive valid set of data 
            //and you can add it to your adapter
        }else{
            //this part will execute, If we are having JSON exception
            // so we need to check the JSON response 
            //and here we should handle this NPE

            //show toast that we are receiving BAD JSON response
        }
    }
}
```

Here is your POJO class

```
class ListItems{
private id,name,description;

public ListItems(){}

public void setId(String id){
this.id=id;
}

public String getId(){
return id;
}

public void setName(String name){
this.name=name;
}

public String getName(){
return name;
}

public void setDescription(String description){
this.description=description;
}

public String getDescription(){
return description;
}
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: should I add something in `onPostExecute` ?

Comment: yes,In onPostExecute() method we receive ArrayList, so here you can perform some logic that you want, like adding these data to ArrayAdapter and so on

Comment: if you want me to do that means, i will

Comment: should I call the `setOnItemClickListener` as well in `onPostExecute` ?

Comment: no, that's not possible, because this is AsyncTask, this will perform in separate thread.

Comment: if my answer solves your problem means please mark this as an answer.

Comment: should I call `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onPostExecute` ?

Comment: yes you can, refer this post http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html for more and complete details about notifyDataSetChange(), this blog post will explain how to use notifyDataSetChange().

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You've got almost everything working here all you need to do is create a new `ListItems` like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String Id = jObj.getString("id");
    String Name = jObj.getString("name");
    String Description = jObj.getString("description");

    ListItems item = new ListItems();
    item.setId(id);
    item.setName(Name);
    item.setDescription(Description);

    itemsArray.add(item);
}
```

Comment: should I return `itemsArray` after the `for` loop instead of null in `doInBackground` ?

Comment: @mori You should, and you should be able to retrieve it in `onPostExecute()` form there you can pass it on to your ListView via CallBack.

Answer (score 1):

Override the postExecute Method like, For adding the items to the arraylist follow the previous answers

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ListItems> items)
{
  myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_row_2rows_subtitle, itemsArray);
//Declare Listview as global
listView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: I already set my adapter in `loadDataViaWS` should put it in `onPostExecute` ?

Comment: Remove the initial declarations of adapter and declare and implement it here. Only listView should be predeclared.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model class `ListItems` is having setter methods like `setId(String id)`, `setName(String name)` and `setDescription(String desc)`.

Your for loop should look like

```
    for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String Id = jObj.getString("id");
            String Name = jObj.getString("name");
            String Description = jObj.getString("description");

            ListItems items = new ListItems();
            items.setId(Id);
            items.setName(Name);
            items.setDescription(Description);

            itemsArray.add(items);
    }
// Notify your adapter here.. after adding data into your `ArrayList`. You should do that stuff in `PostExecute()` method of an `AsyncTask`.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: inside of `doInBackground` i should call the `myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); `?

Comment: No no... notifyDatasetChanged() should always be called on Main thread(The thread that is created UI).

Comment: but can i call it in `onPostExecute()` ?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can.

Answer (score 0):

For the ListView you will have to implement a BaseAdapter that binds your arraylist items to your list of views. Once you call the adapter with the ArrayList, it renders the views onto your ListView. If you fetch items again and there are newer elements from before, just call the notifyDataSetChanged().

This could help : [Android. How does notifyDataSetChanged() method and ListViews work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229817/android-how-does-notifydatasetchanged-method-and-listviews-work)