# Refactoring code to be Generics and functional interface

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, coding-style, functional-interface

I have two interfaces one can be used to find some statistics by Key and Value and the other is used to visit an object and iterate over it, the first one has the following methods:

```
public interface Statistic {

    public String getKey();

    public Object getValue();

    public String getDetails();
}
```

And here is the implementation for it:

```
public class Collector implements Statistic {

    private String key;
    private int val;

    public Collector(String key, int val) {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public void setValue(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDetails() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the other one has the following:

```
public interface StatisticsCollector<T extends Object, S extends Statistic> {

    public String getName();

    public void visit(T object);

    public Iterator<S> calculatedStatistics();
}
```

And here is the implementation for it:

```
public class CalculateFromObject<K, V> implements StatisticsCollector<Object, Collector> {

    EmployeeValidator empValidator = new EmployeeValidator();
    StringValidator strValidator = new StringValidator();

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof String) {
            String str = object.toString();

            int upperCaseCount = strValidator.upperCaseFreq(str);
            strValidator.set.add(new Collector("Upper Case Letters: ", upperCaseCount));
            int lowerCaseCount = strValidator.lowerCaseFreq(str);
            strValidator.set.add(new Collector("Lower Case Letters: ", lowerCaseCount));
            int digitsCount = strValidator.digitFreq(str);
            strValidator.set.add(new Collector("Digits Count: ", digitsCount));
            int wordCount = strValidator.wordFreq(str);
            strValidator.set.add(new Collector("Words Count: ", wordCount));
            int nonWordCount = strValidator.nonWordFreq(str);
            strValidator.set.add(new Collector("Non Word Count: ", nonWordCount));

        } else if (object instanceof Employee) {

            Employee emp = (Employee) object;
            empValidator.salaryValidator(emp);
            empValidator.birthDateValidator(emp);
            empValidator.birthPlaceValidator(emp);
            empValidator.resignationDateValidator(emp);
            empValidator.positionValidator(emp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Collector> calculatedStatistics() {
        return empValidator.set.iterator();
    }


}
```

And in my package I have a bean for Employee which has few properties like firstName, lastName, salary and position with their setters and getters.

I would like to do some validations like get me the number of employees which has a salary of x and been born in 1990 and did the following class for these validations:

```
public class EmployeeValidator {

    public Set<Collector> set = new HashSet<>();

    public void salaryValidator(Employee emp) {
        int count = 0;
        // each collector consist of a condition (function), key, value (always incremented)
        if (emp.getSalary() < 350) {
            set.add(new Collector("Employee with salaries less than 350JD: ", ++count));
        } else if (emp.getSalary() >= 350 && emp.getSalary() < 600) {
            set.add(new Collector("Employee with salaries between 350JD And 600JD: ", ++count));
        } else if (emp.getSalary() >= 600 && emp.getSalary() < 1200) {
            set.add(new Collector("Employee with salaries between 600JD And 1200JD ", ++count));
        } else if (emp.getSalary() >= 1200) {
            set.add(new Collector("Employee with salaries more than 1200JD: ", ++count));
        }

    }

    public void birthDateValidator(Employee emp) {
        for (Collector stats : set) {
            if (("Employees that where born in " + emp.getBirthDate().getYear() + " = ").equals(stats.getKey())) {
                count(stats);
                return;
            }
        }
        set.add(new Collector("Employees that where born in " + emp.getBirthDate().getYear() + " = ", 1));
    }

    public void birthPlaceValidator(Employee emp) {
        for (Collector stats : set) {
            if (("Employees that where born in " + emp.getBirthPlace() + " = ").equals(stats.getKey())) {
                count(stats);
                return;
            }
        }
        set.add(new Collector("Employees that where born in " + emp.getBirthPlace() + " = ", 1));
    }

    public void resignationDateValidator(Employee emp) {
        for (Collector stats : set) {
            if (("Employees that where Resignation in " + emp.getResignationDate().getYear() + " = ").equals(
                    stats.getKey())) {
                count(stats);
                return;
            }
        }
        set.add(new Collector("Employees that where Resignation in " + emp.getResignationDate().getYear() + " = ", 1));
    }

    public void positionValidator(Employee emp) {
        for (Collector stats : set) {
            if (("Employees that occupy the " + emp.getPosition() + " position = ").equals(stats.getKey())) {
                count(stats);
                return;
            }
        }
        set.add(new Collector("Employees that occupy the " + emp.getPosition() + " position = ", 1));
    }

    private void count(Collector stats) {
        int counter = stats.getValue() + 1;
        stats.setValue(counter);
    }
}
```

And I have another class to validate strings and see how many uppercase letters a string has, how many lower case it has...etc

As you can see in the visit method in the CalculateFromObject class im calling all my methods to do the validations, everything is working fine and I am getting the expected results, but my code is not very efficient as I would like to make it generic and make it accept any type of object, I have done few tries but im stuck.

I have tried to write a functional interface called Conditions that has one method that I can pass a condition and check it like the following:

```
public interface Conditions {

    boolean checkCondition(Object obj);

}
```

So can someone suggest what is the best way to change my code to be generic and accept any type of objects like Student for example and to be as clean as possible maybe by applying a design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of overhead in your classes and misunderstanding of interfaces against [POJO's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722251/what-is-pojo-dojo-in-java) (simple classes). On a high level you should do the following:

1). Remove interface `Statistic` and class `Collectors`. They are just incapsulating data. Instead - create a POJO `Employee` with necessary fields + getters + setters. Don't use 'key`-`value`, give those fields meaningful names:

```
public class Employee
{
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private double salary;
        ...
     public String getName() {...}
     public void setName(..) {...}
// other getters / setters
}
```

Create constructor if needed

2) Looks like your `Employee` class is also redundant, remove it. Use new Employee instead
3) Use `Collections` framework to store collections of your employee's instances.

```
`List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
employees.add(new Employee(.... )); `
```

4). Create interface EmployeeValidator with validating methods and implement it:

`public interface EmployeeValidator {
    void validate(List<Employee> employees);
    }`

5) If you want to operate some statistics data, create a separate `Statistics` class which will operate on collections of employees, e.g.

```
public class Statistics {

    public double getAvgSalary(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        double avgSalary = 0;
        for (Employee e : employees) {
        ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant remove the interfaces Statistics and the collector as the task is to implement them

Comment: The main idea is that you're misusing interfaces. Refactor it with the classes and leave necessary ones

Comment: Ok i see what you mean thanks for that, now how can i make it general and make it for rxample easy to implement the same for a Student object?

Comment: And can you explain how am I misusing the interfaces?