# Is java bean and java pojo same?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Is `java bean`and `java POJO` same thing or there are differences?

Comment: No, they aren't.  Rules for Beans are stricter than for POJOs.

Comment: A Java Bean must,
Have a public default constructor &
Be serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All JavaBeans are POJOs but not all POJOs are JavaBeans.

A JavaBean is a Java object that satisfies certain programming conventions:
the JavaBean class must implement either Serializable or Externalizable
the JavaBean class must have a no-arg constructor
all JavaBean properties must public setter and getter methods (as appropriate)
all JavaBean instance variables should be private

Comment: very good answer. In addition to what you have said, some Java extension operations such as persistence and graphics favour JavaBeans over POJOs

Comment: 100% identical with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24886660/2817802) did you just copy it?

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: Nop.. This is what that is taught when You start learning Java...........   ...... .............                                The Java-Beanness of a POJO is that it's public attributes are all accessed via getters and setters that conform to the JavaBeans conventions. 
e.g. 
private String foo;
public String getFoo(){...}
public void setFoo(String foo){...};

Comment: the resemblance is uncanny