# Problems deserializing iso-8601 formatted date from JSON String using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a simple JSON string of the form `{"item":"CDigital_cam_80X","manufacturer":"Canon","model":"95 IS","announced-date":"2009-02-17T19:00:00.000-05:00"}`

I have created a Java Bean and written code to deserialize the string using Gson to get an object but for some reason the announced_date field returns a null every time.

Here is the code snippet for the deserialization

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").create();                    
                    currentProduct = gson.fromJson(currentLine, Product.class);
```

Here is the product class.

```
import java.util.Date;


public class Product {

    private String product_name;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;
    private Date announced_date;

    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family) {
        this.family = family;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Date getAnnounced_date() {
        return announced_date;
    }

    public void setAnnounced_date(Date announced_date) {
        this.announced_date = announced_date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{ \n");
        sb.append(" product_name: "); sb.append(this.getProduct_name()); sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(" manufacturer "); sb.append(this.getManufacturer()); sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(" family: "); sb.append(this.getFamily()); sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(" model: "); sb.append(this.getModel()); sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(" announced_date: "); sb.append(this.getAnnounced_date()); sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("}");

        return sb.toString();
   }
}
```

Here is the result I get when I run the code and print out the preperties of the deserialized object

```
{
item:CDigital_cam_80X
manufacturer Canon
model:95 IS
announced-date:null
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues --

In your JSON, the field is named "announced-date" but in your POJO it is "announced_date".  Notice there is an underscore instead of a dash.  GSON views these as two different fields.  To fix that, use the `@SerializeName` annotation.

```
@SerializedName("announced-date")
private Date announced_date;
```

Second, your data format is off for the time zone specifier.  `Z` should be an `X`.  `Z` does not have a colon (:) in the specification. `X` does.  See [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it like magic. I notice you referred to the product class as a POJO, is it a POJO or a Java Bean or both?

Comment: Your class is both, imo.  See here for a full discussion http://stackoverflow.com/q/1394265/1904517 on the topic.