# Does Eclipse option generate entities from tables generate POJO object or BEAN object?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I am working on one Java project in Eclipse, which uses database with some tables inside it. Initially I used Eclipse option generate entities from tables. Because I have to write something about mu work on this project, I am wondering which type of Java class is generated during this process? Is it Bean or POJO? I think it's Bean because it implements Serializable class, because I think that I had read somewhere that POJO should not extend or implement other predefined classes like Serializable, but I think it's better to ask, than to be sorry later, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is an example of one of the classes:

```
package modeli;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the člankomisije database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Člankomisije.findAll", query="SELECT č FROM Člankomisije č")
public class Člankomisije implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idČlanKomisije;

    private String vrstaČlana;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Ocjenjujetemu
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="člankomisije")
    private Ocjenjujetemu ocjenjujetemu;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Zapisnik
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="člankomisije")
    private List<Zapisnik> zapisniks;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Komisija
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idKomisija")
    private Komisija komisija;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Nastavnik
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idNastavnik")
    private Nastavnik nastavnik;

    public Člankomisije() {
    }

    public int getIdČlanKomisije() {
        return this.idČlanKomisije;
    }

    public void setIdČlanKomisije(int idČlanKomisije) {
        this.idČlanKomisije = idČlanKomisije;
    }

    public String getVrstaČlana() {
        return this.vrstaČlana;
    }

    public void setVrstaČlana(String vrstaČlana) {
        this.vrstaČlana = vrstaČlana;
    }

    public Ocjenjujetemu getOcjenjujetemu() {
        return this.ocjenjujetemu;
    }

    public void setOcjenjujetemu(Ocjenjujetemu ocjenjujetemu) {
        this.ocjenjujetemu = ocjenjujetemu;
    }

    public List<Zapisnik> getZapisniks() {
        return this.zapisniks;
    }

    public void setZapisniks(List<Zapisnik> zapisniks) {
        this.zapisniks = zapisniks;
    }

    public Zapisnik addZapisnik(Zapisnik zapisnik) {
        getZapisniks().add(zapisnik);
        zapisnik.setČlankomisije(this);

        return zapisnik;
    }

    public Zapisnik removeZapisnik(Zapisnik zapisnik) {
        getZapisniks().remove(zapisnik);
        zapisnik.setČlankomisije(null);

        return zapisnik;
    }

    public Komisija getKomisija() {
        return this.komisija;
    }

    public void setKomisija(Komisija komisija) {
        this.komisija = komisija;
    }

    public Nastavnik getNastavnik() {
        return this.nastavnik;
    }

    public void setNastavnik(Nastavnik nastavnik) {
        this.nastavnik = nastavnik;
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like POJOs don't follow specific conventions. Then a bean might be a POJO as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394292/1199132 Anyway, for the code you posted I would say the best is to call it a JPA Entity.

Comment: Agreed with @XtremeBiker. If you wish a formal definition of JPA entity: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejbs003.htm