# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [FlightNo] not found on type [com.project70.Flight]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here is the method inside controller class taking the model object list

```
@RequestMapping("cancel")
public String listTicket(Model m) {
    System.out.println("Inside listTicket method");
    List<Flight> list=fs.listAll();
    m.addAttribute("list",list);
    return "cancelTicket";
}
```

Service class method

```
public List<Flight> listAll(){
    return repo.findAll();
}
```

Model class with getters and setters of respective fields.
I have used all the required annoations but haven't posted here, so ignore that
(Annotations omitted: `@Entity` & `@Table`)

```
public class Flight {
    
    private int id;
    private String FlightNo;
    private String FlightName;
    private String FlightFrom;
    private String FlightTo;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFlightNo() {
        return FlightNo;
    }

    public void setFlightNo(String flightNo) {
        FlightNo = flightNo;
    }

    public String getFlightName() {
        return FlightName;
    }

    public void setFlightName(String flightName) {
        FlightName = flightName;
    }

    public String getFlightFrom() {
        return FlightFrom;
    }

    public void setFlightFrom(String flightFrom) {
        FlightFrom = flightFrom;
    }

    public String getFlightTo() {
        return FlightTo;
    }

    public void setFlightTo(String flightTo) {
        FlightTo = flightTo;
    }

}
```

JSP page scriptlet

```
    <c:forEach var="li" items="${list}">
        <tr>
            <td>${li.id}</td>
            <td>${li.FlightNo}</td>
            <td>${li.FlightName}</td>
            <td>${li.FlightFrom}</td>
            <td>${li.FlightTo}</td>
            <td><a href="">Cancel Ticket</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Here is the error

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [FlightNo] not found on type [com.cognizant.project70.Flight]
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:260) ~[tomcat-el-api-9.0.37.jar:3.0.FR]
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:212) ~[tomcat-el-api-9.0.37.jar:3.0.FR]
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:333) ~[tomcat-el-api-9.0.37.jar:3.0.FR]
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:92) ~[tomcat-el-api-9.0.37.jar:3.0.FR]
at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:125) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) ~[tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190) ~[tomcat-jasper-el-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:701) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.jsp.pages.cancelTicket_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(cancelTicket_jsp.java:202) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jsp.pages.cancelTicket_jsp._jspService(cancelTicket_jsp.java:150) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-servlet-api-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: anyone knows whats wrong with the code why am getting this kind of error in filed FlightNo while i have used respective getter method still getting this error

Comment: Appreciate you saved space by not posting the annotations, but can you at least post the annotation for `FlightNo` please?

Comment: @Romio Ranjan Sahoo Properties in your html template (jsp page) need to be in camel case. Ex: ${li.FlightNo} should be ${li.flightNo} when you drop the "get" part wrt your Flight object. You will need to fix all the refs in your page too.

Comment: @nullTerminator i have't used any annotation for FlightNo field

Comment: @MuffinMan yes its working now, thanks a lot for your help....but one doubt i have we only need to specify fields in camel case in view right regardless of whatever written in model

Comment: Yes, I wanted to see if you'd actually mapped the field name to `FlightNo` instead of the default `flightNo`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the FlightNo and other field accessors don't match the bean naming conventions and that's why the exception is thrown. They should be as follows:

Use camel case pattern for all the variables like below.

Change fields to flightNo,flightName etc in model class and view page. By making first letter lowercase.

And then generate public getters and setters.

Comment: Variable names in the model do not need to be camel case for properties of the model to be accessible.

Comment: But it's always a good practice to use coding standards. Also let him confirm before you downvote the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alien it is wroking only need to change the view page and i got your point of doing same for model for good practice..Thanks for the help

Comment: @Alien. No. Your answer is wrong and is of poor quality, and the information you are providing is misleading. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394265/what-is-the-difference-between-a-javabean-and-a-pojo